# How to pass a variable into argparse in python

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script func.py that contains argparse and takes a file

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
parser.add_argument('-i', dest='ifile', metavar="FILE", help='input file')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This ifile is basically just a name of that file in a directory

```
filename = 'PATH TO FILE' + args.ifile
```

If I have a variable that contains the name of the file how can I pass the variable to the argparse so that it would take the string value of the variable? 
Something like this :

```
new_file = 'text_file.txt'
func.py -i new_file
filename = 'PATH TO FILE' + 'text_file.txt'
```

What I am getting now is this:

```
new_file = "text_file.txt'
python func.py -I new_file
filename = 'PATH TO FILE' + 'new_file'
```

And then obviously an error message that it cannot find the file.

Comment: Can you post a more detailed example? I cant even figure out where are those lines coming from

Comment: For what reason do you want the command line argument to refer to a variable name? I suspect that you are going the wrong way to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @user10605163 I need to run func.py inside jupyter notebook (! func.py -i new_file) Unfortunately there is no other way I can run this script

Comment: Please add Jupyter to the question. Normally this isn't a problem in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to do:

```
$ new_file="text_file.txt"
$ ./func.py -I $new_file
```

Your args variable in `Python` should then contain `ifile='text_file.txt'`:

```
text_file.txt
```